# About return in C++

Tags: c++

Sorry for this newbie question, but I can't find on google what I need to know.

I understand *return*, but don't understand this... What does it mean this?

```
  return (tail+1)%N == head%N;
```

Thanks a lot for patience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns `true` or `false`, depending on whether the expression is true or not.

It's the same as:

```
if ( (tail+1)%N == head%N )
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

Comment: Except that it's more idiomatic, and more readable to someone who knows C++.

Comment: IMO it needs the whole expression bracketed (i.e. `return ((tail+1)%N == head%N);` as in the `if`) to be more readable. But I just like excess brackets to remove any ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

this

> (tail+1)%N == head%N

returns a boolean value, either true or false. This statement means that after adding 1 to trail (trail + 1) and the remainder obtained after division with N is equal to remainder of  head divided with N. % is used for division with remainder

> (%). Modulo is the operation that gives the remainder of a division of two values.

Check this link for c++ operators : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Answer (score 2):

you're returning a boolean value. The value represents whether or not the remainder of (tail+1) divided by N is the same as that of head.

Answer (score 2):

It evaluates the expression, and return the result. In this case it's two modulo operations that are compared, and the result is either `true` or `false` which will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

it returns true if remainder of the division for tail + 1 and head is the same

for example if tail is 2, head is 1 and N is 2

(tail + 1) % N is 1

head % N is 1 too

so whole expression returns true

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:**

Because of the `==` operator your function will return a `bool`, meaning it can only be `true`or `false`. An equivalent would be something like:

```
return 5 == 4;
```

which would return `false` since 5 is not equal to 4.

**Long Answer:**

Instead of writing this in a single line you could split it up into more lines of code. Let's just assume that `tail`, `head` and `N` are integer values, then you could write it like this:

```
int x, y;
x = (tail+1)%N;
y = head%N;
if ( x == y )
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Now in this code there may be also that `%`confuses you a bit. The `%`is called the `Modulus Operator` and can give you the remainder of arithmetic operations. In a simple example this would mean:

`10 % 3 = 1` because `10/3` is 3 with a remainder of 1. So to make it more clear let's just make another example with your specific problem:

Lets just assume that `tail=10`,`head=6` and `N=2`. Then you would get something like this:

```
x = (10+1)%2
x = 11 % 2
x = 1

y = 6 % 2
y = 0

y != x
```

This would return `false` cause `x` and `y` are not equal. ( If you would run your code with the given example values )

To learn more about `Modulus` you can look [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html), or just on any other basic C++ Tutorial.